# Redirect [http and/or non-www] to [https://www.] in ONE redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have setup redirects in the htaccess file. It redirects all non-https and non-www requests to https-www versions.

Following are the rules I have used in the .htaccess file:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

The redirect works fine. My only problem here is that it requires 2 redirects. Let's say my website is example.com.

When I open example.com, it first redirects to https://example.com and then it gets redirected to https://www.example.com

So, I get the response code after two redirects. 301-301-200

Now my question is: Is there any way to have it done in a single redirect?

Comment: The rules you've posted should already do that in a single redirect. The first rule redirects to www + HTTPS. Make sure you've cleared your browser cache.

Comment: But the tool at https://httpstatus.io/ tells there are 2 redirects involved here with http://example.com

Comment: What exactly is the tool reporting in terms of redirecting from/to? What do you see in the browser (devtools)? (You don't need an external tool to test this.) It would seem either that tool is "wrong" or something else is performing these redirects. The first rule clearly redirects non-www to www (+ HTTPS). The second rule would not be processed in this scenario when requesting the non-www hostname. Try changing the response code in `.htaccess` to 302 (as you should be using when testing anyway) - does the reported status code change in that tool?

Comment: This is the redirects path as shown in the devtools: (http://+example.com/) 301 redirects to (https://+example.com/) which 301 redirects to (https://+www.example.com/) which returns 200=OK

So, there are two 301 redirects involved here. I want to cut it into a single 301 redirect. Like, http://+example.com/ should go to https://+www.example.com/ as one redirect.

Comment: _Aside:_ What's the `+` in the hostname? Use backticks to format inline code and URLs.

Comment: You need to find out where that initial HTTP to HTTPS redirect is coming from. It's not coming from the directives you've posted. Do you have any other directives in your `.htaccess` file? Examine the HTTP response headers for the initial direct response (and update your question) - this _might_ give a clue as to what is triggering the redirect. Maybe there is a frontend proxy that is "upgrading" the request? Maybe the `.htaccess` directives aren't actually doing anything and your application is triggering the redirect?

Comment: However, this isn't necessarily a "problem". Redirecting directly from HTTP to HTTPS on the same host is actually a requirement if you should implement HSTS (which is generally recommended). This is also an "edge" case. How many requests do you actually get for HTTP + non-canonical hostname?